# Share a Tableau dashboard built on server with a Tableau Cloud user

Tags: tableau-desktop

We have a mixed set of licenses at my organization: some of use are on Tableau Server, others are on Tableau Cloud. I am having difficulty figuring out how to share a dashboard I made in Tableau Server with a user who only has Tableau Cloud access. I have been told this is possible but have yet to find any documentation laying out the specific steps.

Is it possible to share a Tableau Server dashboard with a Tableau Cloud user?

When I go to share a dashboard the only users I see available for sharing are those at my organization who have Tableau Server. I tried sharing just the URL with a Tableau Cloud user and they were unable to open the link.

Comment: try merging all your licenses under a domain name. Contact you Tableau vendor

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try and report back if it works.